# Iterator String issue

Tags: c++, string, vector, iterator

I have a string vector and i want to iterate through the vector and then output the contents of that vector one the screen (GUI)

The method used to populate the page is **setValue(std::string);**

question is, is there a way i could associate a string to the **iterator** so then i can parse that **string** into the method and output the contents

So i need to somehow get **string str** equal that **iterator** and then i can parse **str** into the **parameter**

```
**std::string str;**
for(it = display.begin(); it < display.end(); it++)
{


}
```

Comment: I don’t think you mean “parse”, it makes no sense here. Do you simply want to pass the current item to the method?

Comment: As this is homework. Why not tell us what the real question is and what part you are hacing difficulty with. We will then give you appropriate hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you are asking how to retrieve `string` from `vector<string>::iterator i`.

Answer is `*i`.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void foo(string& s)
{
    cout << s << endl; // print argument
}

int main(void)
{
    vector<string> display;
    display.push_back("string1");
    display.push_back("string2");
    display.push_back("string3");

    for (vector<string>::iterator i = display.begin(); i != display.end(); ++i)
    {
        foo(*i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for a very good answer _and_ for bothering. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Thank you. +1 for recognizing Alizée! ;)